# XML Parsing in swift: no description parser error

Tags: swift, parsing, xml-parsing, swift4

I'm trying to parse a GPX (geolocation) file as a XML file using XMLParser. I'm also trying to wrap some functions around to make it easier.

I'm stuck trying to run my code with an error in my parser and "NIL" in the debugDescription of the parserError... Any idea what's going on here ?

Here is the code :

```
import Foundation

class Wpt {
    var lat: Float?;
    var long: Float?;
    var name = "";
    var time = "";
}

var gpx = [Wpt]();
var wpt = Wpt();
var foundCharacters = "";

class Parser: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {

    func test(filepath: URL) {
        let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: filepath)!
        parser.delegate = self
        let success = parser.parse()
        if success {
            print("done")
        }
        else {
            print(parser.parserError.debugDescription)
        }
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser,
                didStartElement elementName: String,
                namespaceURI: String?,
                qualifiedName qName: String?,
                attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {

        if elementName == "wpt" {

            if let lat = attributeDict["lat"] {
                wpt.lat = Float(lat);
            }

            if let long = attributeDict["long"] {
                wpt.long = Float(long);
            }

        }

    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser,
                foundCharacters string: String) {
        foundCharacters += string;
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser,
                didEndElement elementName: String,
                namespaceURI: String?,
                qualifiedName qName: String?) {

        if elementName == "name" {
            wpt.name = foundCharacters;
        }

        if elementName == "time" {
            wpt.time = foundCharacters;
        }

        if elementName == "wpt" {
            gpx.append(wpt);
        }

        foundCharacters = "";
    }

    func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {
        for wpx in gpx {
            print("\(wpx.name)\n\(wpx.time)");
            print("\n")
        }
    }

}

var filepath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Document/Github/GPXParser/GPXParser/Location.gpx")
Parser().test(filepath: filepath)
```

And here is the GPX file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode">

    <wpt lat="37.331705" lon="-122.030237">
        <name>Cupertino</name>

        <time>2014-09-24T14:55:37Z</time>
    </wpt>
    <wpt lat="37.331285" lon="-122.039837">
        <name>Paris</name>

        <time>2014-09-24T14:58:37Z</time>
    </wpt>

</gpx>
```

If you prefer the link to the project on my [GitHub](https://github.com/maximebrunengo/GPXParser)

Fell free to criticize, first Swift Project for me :)

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, changes are committed on gitHub

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp Well, I'm testing the boolean (parsing.parse()) and the boolean is false...

Comment: I ran your code and it parsed the location data without problems, printing "done" and no error message. – Double-check that the path to the file is correct.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, the problem was in my path, I wasn't taking the absolute path.